# How to manage local accounts on a windows office network?

Tags: networking, local-area-network, user-accounts

I've recently had to assume the role of a network admin in a small office running a network of about 20 computers with a main server running Windows Server 2019.  This server contains our AD as well as all the shared files.

**My question:**

What is an efficient/effective way to manage the local accounts of the network?  The windows AD is more than enough for me to manage the *domain* accounts, but I still haven't found any useful tool to manage the *local* accounts (i.e. the Windows account on each computer).

For instance, are there tools/apps/softwares to allow me to manage passwords of the local accounts (just like I can do with the domain accounts on the windows AD), deleting/editing/creating the windows accounts/users on these computers, or setting up a general security policy for all the local accounts of the network (e.g. passwords should be changed every months, should respect specific criteria, etc...), etc...?

Thanks!

Comment: The main point of a directory service like AD is that you don't need any local accounts (once your clients have joined the AD domain). Just use AD accounts throughout. You can set password policies over GPO.

Comment: @Zac67  I see. If using AD accounts throughout is not possible atm, what would be an alternative solution in that case?

Comment: The alternative is a huge bunch of scripting. Why can't your machines join the AD?

Answer (score 1):

You can use Group Policies to remove, add, set password etc. for local accounts as well.

However, this requires the machines in question to be added to Active Directory, which defeats the purpose of creating local accounts. In general, you should avoid any local accounts like the plague, and generally the Group Policies mentioned above are used just to remove and/or disable any local machine accounts in a AD environment.

Long story short, join all machines to AD and stop messing with local accounts.